# Массив Python большие квадраты

Tags: python, массивы, if

Помогите улучшить решение для задачи:

Заполните прямоугольный массив целыми числами квадратами размера 2×2 из единиц, квадраты идут в шахматном порядке, начиная с левого верхнего угла.

```
Пример для n=7m=10
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
```

Мое решение

```
n, m = 7, 10
a = []
arr = [[0 for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]

for i in range(len(arr)):
    a.append([])
for j in range(len(arr[i])):
    if i%2 != 0:
        x = ((i+j)%4)%3
        if x == 2:
            x = 1
    elif ((i+j+1)%4)%3 == 0:
        x= 0
    else:
        x = 1
    a[i].append(x)

for k in a:
    print(*k)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
n, m = 7, 10
a = [[~(i ^ j) >> 1 & 1 for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]

for k in a:
    print(*k)
```

```
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
```

Comment: Мощь. Что написано понятно, а вот почему, т.е. как работает алгоритм - нет )))

Comment: @Pavel Может так будет проще для понимания `1 - (i // 2 + j // 2) % 2`

Comment: а главное что если менять цифры, то получаются другие матрицы, т.е. можно сделать квадраты больше или меньше, можно прямоугольники, можно другие цифры. В общем мощь. Буду качать мозг)

Comment: @Pavel Если рассматривать арифметическое решение: Деление координат ячейки на размеры прямоугольника дает нам координаты прямоугольника, в котором она находится. Если обе координаты четные или обе нечетные, например `0, 0`, `0, 2`, `1, 1` их сумма будет четной, ставим `1`, если четность разная `0, 1`, `1, 0`, `1, 2` - сумма нечетная, ставим `0`.

Comment: Поясните вот этот синтаксис пожалуйста ~(i^J)>>1&1

Comment: @StanislavRepin ^ - это побитовое исключающее или, >> побитовое смещение (по факту это деление на 2 без остатака // 2 ), ~ это инверсия и еще минус один от результата (погуглите про тильду в питоне), &1 - логическое побитовое И c 1 (По факту это модуль при делении на 2, т.е. %2). 

Как правда из исключающего или получаются квадраты я сам не понял, проще с цифрами))

Comment: @StanislavRepin побитовое исключающее или можно рассматривать как побитовое сравнение. Если биты на одинаковых позициях одинаковые - `0`, если разные - `1`, а тильда инвертирует этот результат. Таким образом сравниваем вторые биты координат. Если они одинаковые - ставим `1`, если разные - `0`. Если совсем не понятно, возьмите решение из комментария.

Comment: @extrn - круть!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

n, m = 7, 10
arr = [[0 for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]

tr = 1
for i, r in enumerate(arr):
    if tr > 0: tc = 1
    else:      tc = -1
    for j, c in enumerate(r):
        if tc > 0:
            arr[i][j] = 1
        tc += 1
        if tc == 3:
            tc = -1
    tr += 1
    if tr == 3:
            tr = -1

pp(arr)
```